# Hide the applications from apps list?

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop

I want to hide the installed 3 rd party apps in android. I hided the app icon in app drawer using Nova launcher, but those apps still visible in settings > apps list? Is there any way to hide it from apps list? I am using lollipop 5.0.2 and phone not rooted.

Comment: Can you please mention you device in your question..?

Comment: You can use "Hide App-Hide Application" from play store, but it needs rooted phone, It locks your app, you even change the aap hider name to others like "settings" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

For Samsung devices, root is not required. You can do it using app drawer:

1. Click on Apps button on your home screen.
2. Click on menu button( left soft key button).
3. Tap on hide apps and select the apps you want to hide.

Similarly on the HTC devices.

Answer (score 0):

there's no way to hide an app from apps list in settings unless the phone is rooted.

Comment: That's not completely true. One could use an [app locker](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_applocker) to hide the entire settings section altogether :) (also see: [kiosk-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/kiosk-mode/info))

Comment: But that's not what the OP asked

Comment: You've missed two characters, let me emphasize them: **:)** (IOW: "just kidding") The OP nowhere stated he wanted to see the *other* apps, so hiding the entire thing would match the question, taken literally :) But yes, if my "solution" would be acceptable, I'd posted it as an answer. So apart from that, I don't know anything to be done in this regard without (or even with) involving root – except for modifying the packages (`.apk`) themselves. There is a "hide" flag somewhere (that's how some carrier-specific apps are hidden when using a different carrier).